# Using Windows 7 with Dual Monitors to access Headless PC via Remote Desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop, remote, headless

I work remotely and access a computer in my office.  That computer is headless and I use cisco vpn and RDC to access it.  (Both machines are running windows 7 pro) At home I have 3 monitors and when I connect I am only able to view the remote computer as having a single monitor.  Is there a way to trick the headless computer into thinking it has 2 or 3 monitors attached so I can use some of the common features like maximize or using the windows key to re size and shift windows around.

I have tried the /span command but it does not work correctly as it thinks you have one large monitor instead of 2 different one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Remote Desktop Multimon Feature: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx)

EDIT: I apologize, after further research this feature is not available on Windows 7 Pro. You can find more information here: [RDC FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows)

Comment: This still seems to work with a single monitor.  The computer I am connecting is headless so it doesnt have any monitors.  I would like to trick it into thinking it has 2 or 3.

Comment: I apologize, after further research this feature is not available on Windows 7 Pro. You can find more information here: [RDC FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions)